# How to pass arguments through recursive (tree) evaluation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm writing a function that takes a composite interaction and recursively enacts it by looking up the primitive values. It's basically a kind of tree (I think). However, it needs to keep track of the last 2 primitive values it checked while doing this. In a non-functional language, I could just use global variables, but I'm not sure how to manage this in Haskell.

Perhaps I could pass a list of experiments and make it return (Inter,Experiment), and then add that in where marked below? And to not mess (Composite pre (enact post)) up, I'd get the call in the prior line and only use the Inter value. ... Great, typing it up I may've found something complicated. However, I'd appreciate pointers if there's a more elegant way to deal with this.

```
data Inter = None | Primitive Experiment Result | Composite Inter Inter deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

enact :: Inter -> Inter
enact (Composite pre post) =
    let enacted = enact pre
    -- add to eHist here, pass it on. Reconstruct it after you finish?
    in if enacted /= pre
        then enacted
        else (Composite pre (enact post))
enact (Primitive e _) = (Primitive e (getResult10 e))
enact None = None

-- Environment040
getResult40 :: [Experiment] -> Experiment -> Result
getResult40 (pre:pen:_) cur
    | pen /= cur && pre == cur = R2
    | otherwise = R1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the rest of your code, so can't compose the remainder. Here is the idea of how you could pass "global state" along as the `enact` computes the branches of the tree:

```
data Inter e r = None | Primitive e r
                      | Composite (Inter e r) (Inter e r)
                      deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
enact :: (Eq e, Eq r) => Inter e r -> State a (Inter e r)
enact (Composite pre post) = do
      enacted <- enact pre
      x <- get -- and then you can use x, if enact depends on the last
               -- two Primitives seen
      if enacted /= pre
      then return enacted
      else do
             post' <- enact post
             return $ Composite pre post'
enact (Primitive e r) = do
          x <- get
          put $ modify x somehow -- you wanted to keep track of
                                 -- the last two Primitives
          return $ Primitive e r
enact None = return None
```

I had to replace the types with `e` and `r` only to make sure it compiles; and, to be honest, I don't miss it. Now you could use `get` and `put` to query the state (of type `a` here, but you may be more specific - e.g. a tuple of past Primitive values you were thinking of), and set for use by evaluation further down the tree walk. Then you can use `runState` or `evalState` to feed the initial state (eg the initial tuple representing no Primitive values found yet), and get back either the tree of `Inters`, or the tree and the final state.

Comment: You should include all of the necessary `import` statements.

Comment: import Control.Monad.State

Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was wondering about. Thanks to you, learning to use State in practice was not that difficult ^__^
It worked like a charm. (e and r work fine. Always wondering how to weigh descriptive vs. concise names. I should'e included those too though. Sorry.)